# Does not the wire signal affect in sequencial logic?

Tags: verilog

I want to make 1 delay signal with an wire signal.
Let's here my case.

```
wire done;
reg done_d0;  

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
begin
if(!rst) done_d0 <= 0;
else done_d0 <= done;
end
```

But done_d0 does not have a delay when done is high.
Both are triggered at the same time.

What am I missing ?

Comment: how are you driving `done`. NB try `done <= 1'b1;`

Comment: Show use your test code. Also, while not your what is causing the issue, *always* use ```begin``` and ```end``` statements around your if's and else's as it makes the code far more readable and means mistakes are less likely (and easier to find).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`done` is probably being updated before the always block is executed within the same time-step (i.e. zero-time).

A `wire` can only be assigned with a continuous blocking assignment. Non-blocking assignments (`<=`) can only be done to `reg`. If the assignments of the `reg`s that drive `done` are changed from blocking (`=`) to non-blocking (`<=`), you should be the desired result.

A non-blocking assignment does an immediate evaluation with an delayed update. This allows the correct values to be evaluated without impacting the evaluation of a depended expression. Note: the delayed update is in the verilog time-step scheduler; it will not have a visible delay in waveform.

Use non-blocking assignments on `reg` you want treated as a flop. Any `reg` used for combinational logic or clock generation should use blocking. There will be race conditions if non-blocking is used for combinational logic or clock.

```
...

reg clk;
reg a,b,c;

always #10 clk = !clk;

assign done = func(a,b,c);

initial begin
  clk=0;
  a <= 1'b0;
  b <= 1'b0;
  c <= 1'b0;
  #10;
  a <= 1'b1;
  #20;
  b <= 1'b1;
  a <= 1'b0;
  #20;
  a <= 1'b1;
  c <= 1'b1;
  #20;
  a <= 1'b0;
  b <= 1'b0;
end
```